# Select random hidden cell with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding and I have to make a game in javascript where a random is cell selected and the player has to try and guess the correct cell (a cell which is chosen at random) in the table. It is then supposed to tell you that you have selected the right cell. I am having trouble figuring out how to do so. All i have right now is the table and some of the cells highlight red when clicked.
All replies wil be appreciated

Heres all the code i have so far if you need it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

 

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Document</title>

 

    <style>

        body {

            text-align: center;

        }

 

        table,

        th,

        td {

            border: 0px solid white;

            border-collapse: collapse;

            width: 45%;

            height: 55px;

            text-align: center;

            vertical-align: center;

            table-layout: fixed;

        }

 

        table.center {

            margin-left: auto;

            margin-right: auto;

        }

 

        .Tableheader {

            border: 0px solid white

        }

 

        .TableCell {

            background-color: aqua;

            border: 2px solid black;

        }

 

        .button {

            padding: 5px;

            background-color: #dcdcdc;

            border: 1px solid #666;

            color: #000;

            margin-top: 10px;

        }

 

        button:hover {

            color: yellow;

        }

 

        .TableCell:hover {

            background-color: rgb(255, 230, 0);

        }

    </style>

</head>

 

</body>

 <div id="Table">
<h2>Hurkles</h2>
<p> Click a Cell to Find Hurkles</p>
<table>

    <table id="tableID" class="center">

        <tr>
            <td id="R0C0" class="Tableheader"></td>
            <td id="R0C2" class="Tableheader">A</td>
            <td id="R0C3" class="Tableheader">B</td>
            <td id="R0C1" class="Tableheader">C</td>
            <td id="R0C4" class="Tableheader">D</td>
            <td id="R0C5" class="Tableheader">E</td>
            <td id="R0C6" class="Tableheader">F</td>
            <td id="R0C7" class="Tableheader">G</td>
            <td id="R0C8" class="Tableheader">H</td>
            <td id="R0C9" class="Tableheader">I</td>
            <td id="R0C10" class="Tableheader">J</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R1C0" class="Tableheader">1</td>
            <td id="R1C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R2C0" class="Tableheader">2</td>
            <td id="R2C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R3C0" class="Tableheader">3</td>
            <td id="R3C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R4C0" class="Tableheader">4</td>
            <td id="R4C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R5C0" class="Tableheader">5</td>
            <td id="R5C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R6C0" class="Tableheader">6</td>
            <td id="R6C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R7C0" class="Tableheader">7</td>
            <td id="R7C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R8C0" class="Tableheader">8</td>
            <td id="R8C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R9C0" class="Tableheader">9</td>
            <td id="R9C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R10C0" class="Tableheader">10</td>
            <td id="R10C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>

        </tr>

    </table>
</div>

 

    <script>


function tableText(col){
    if (typeof event!=='undefined')
        el=event.srcElement
        for (var i = 0; i < el.parentNode.cells.length; i++)
            el.parentNode.cells[i].style.backgroundColor=''
        el.style.backgroundColor=col
}
    </script>

 

</html>

</script>

 

</html>
```

Comment: First of all you have to decide what it means "correct",  are you going to assign a "correct" cell randomly, or following a rational pattern ?

Comment: You could place a `data-target` attribute in the one cell yo want your users to find and then check in your click handler `tableText()`, whether the clicked cell has this attribute set or not.

Comment: i would pick up two random numbers, one for row and another for column, and pick the corresponding cell, i will need to have a min/max, ex : `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);`, for a number between 0 and 10, then you concat it : `'R' + rowIndex + 'C' + colIndex`

Comment: Then i would simply replace the onclick with js on the correct cell by something else, like `document.querySelector('#R' + rowIndex + 'C' + colIndex).onclick = () => { tableCell('green');}`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

 

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Document</title>

 

    <style>

        body {

            text-align: center;

        }

 

        table,

        th,

        td {

            border: 0px solid white;

            border-collapse: collapse;

            width: 45%;

            height: 55px;

            text-align: center;

            vertical-align: center;

            table-layout: fixed;

        }

 

        table.center {

            margin-left: auto;

            margin-right: auto;

        }

 

        .Tableheader {

            border: 0px solid white

        }

 

        .TableCell {

            background-color: aqua;

            border: 2px solid black;

        }

 

        .button {

            padding: 5px;

            background-color: #dcdcdc;

            border: 1px solid #666;

            color: #000;

            margin-top: 10px;

        }

 

        button:hover {

            color: yellow;

        }

 

        .TableCell:hover {

            background-color: rgb(255, 230, 0);

        }

    </style>

</head>

 

</body>

 <div id="Table">
<h2>Hurkles</h2>
<p> Click a Cell to Find Hurkles</p>
<table>

    <table id="tableID" class="center">

        <tr>
            <td id="R0C0" class="Tableheader"></td>
            <td id="R0C1" class="Tableheader">A</td>
            <td id="R0C2" class="Tableheader">B</td>
            <td id="R0C3" class="Tableheader">C</td>
            <td id="R0C4" class="Tableheader">D</td>
            <td id="R0C5" class="Tableheader">E</td>
            <td id="R0C6" class="Tableheader">F</td>
            <td id="R0C7" class="Tableheader">G</td>
            <td id="R0C8" class="Tableheader">H</td>
            <td id="R0C9" class="Tableheader">I</td>
            <td id="R0C10" class="Tableheader">J</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R1C0" class="Tableheader">1</td>
            <td id="R1C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R2C0" class="Tableheader">2</td>
            <td id="R2C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R3C0" class="Tableheader">3</td>
            <td id="R3C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R4C0" class="Tableheader">4</td>
            <td id="R4C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R5C0" class="Tableheader">5</td>
            <td id="R5C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R6C0" class="Tableheader">6</td>
            <td id="R6C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R7C0" class="Tableheader">7</td>
            <td id="R7C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R8C0" class="Tableheader">8</td>
            <td id="R8C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R9C0" class="Tableheader">9</td>
            <td id="R9C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="R10C0" class="Tableheader">10</td>
            <td id="R10C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>

        </tr>

    </table>
</div>

 

    <script>


   

     function tableText(col){
        if (typeof event!=='undefined')
            el=event.srcElement
            for (var i = 0; i < el.parentNode.cells.length; i++)
                el.parentNode.cells[i].style.backgroundColor=''
            el.style.backgroundColor=col
    }
    let colIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
    let rowIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
    console.log('col:' + ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'][colIndex-1], 'row:' + rowIndex);
    document.querySelector('#R' + rowIndex + 'C' + colIndex).onclick = () => { 
        tableText('green');
    }

    </script>

 

</html>

</script>

 

</html>
```

note that your first cell is R1C1, it would be easier to start from zero instead